# How to add legends to a plot i made using a for loop in seaborn?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, seaborn

I made a distribution plot using `sns.distplot()` for multiple columns in a `pd.DataFrame` using a `for` loop:

```
for i in heatmap_df.columns[1:6]:
    sns.distplot(df[i], hist=False)
```

So there's a kde line of different colours for each of the columns on the same graph. How do I add a legend to specify which color is for which column? Or is there a special kind of plot that allows me do this without using a `for` loop at all?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about putting `label` in `sns`:

```
df = sns.load_dataset('iris')

for i in df.columns[:4]:
    sns.distplot(df[i], hist=False, label=i)
```

Output:

[image]

And without for loop:

```
df.iloc[:,:4].plot.kde()
```

Output:

[image]